# Passing URL Variables Into FormAssembly Form Field

Tags: javascript, forms, url

Anyone have experience passing URL variables into form fields (hidden type ideally) using FormAssembly specifically? The URL includes marketing data I would like to include when a form is submitted. I've been able to parse the URL parameter values and store them in session storage using the code below. For example my URL could be 'www.domain.com/?utm_source=sourceval&utm_medium=mediumval'.  Upon inspecting a page I see a [key:value] of "utm_source:sourceval". Where I run into a problem is taking that key:value and populating a form field value. There is a similar(ish) topic [How to put the variable field names into the hidden fields on a FormAssembly form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57583573/how-to-put-the-variable-field-names-into-the-hidden-fields-on-a-formassembly-for), but I can't quite follow it.  I'm fairly new so any help on not only proposed scripts, but where to put them (on website, in header..or...in form html...) is helpful.  I've been trying to figure this out for some time.

```
<script>
var queryForm = function(settings){
  var reset = settings && settings.reset ? settings.reset : false;
  var self = window.location.toString();
  var querystring = self.split("?");
  if (querystring.length > 1) {
    var pairs = querystring[1].split("&");
    for (i in pairs) {
      var keyval = pairs[i].split("=");
      if (reset || sessionStorage.getItem(keyval[0]) === null) {
        sessionStorage.setItem(keyval[0], keyval[1]);
      }
    }
  }
  var hiddenFields = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=hidden]");
  for (var i=0; i<hiddenFields.length; i++) {
    var param = sessionStorage.getItem(hiddenFields[i].name);
    if (param) document.getElementById(hiddenFields[i].name).value = param;
  }
}
queryForm();
</script>
```

Comment: Also review this thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59166051/display-parsed-url-value/59258446?noredirect=1#comment104759048_59258446) for additional insights.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am trying to do the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I found a way to make this work.  I put an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I must preface that I am not a developer by any stretch of the imagination. I just happen to find something that worked for me.  If you are a developer and can accomplish this better, please contribute. Codepen.io was really helpful in troubleshooting.

Within my form I embedded the below. It was placed below the hidden fields but above the submit button.

- The "tfa" values will have to match your specific forms tfa values.
- The "var" values will be the parsed URL data name from session storage.

```html
<script>
    document.getElementById("tfa_1").value = sessionStorage.getItem('var1');
    document.getElementById("tfa_2").value = sessionStorage.getItem('var2'); 
    document.getElementById("tfa_3").value = sessionStorage.getItem('var3'); 
    document.getElementById("tfa_4").value = sessionStorage.getItem('var4'); 
    document.getElementById("tfa_5").value = sessionStorage.getItem('var5'); 
    document.getElementById("tfa_6").value = sessionStorage.getItem('var6'); 
    document.getElementById("tfa_7").value = sessionStorage.getItem('var7');
</script>
```